# Can I use YEAR(CURDATE()) within a like statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

In a SQL script I'm trying to get data based on the year within a string value field. Each year the table adds a new row for the current year . So the ID_TYPE_NAME column has a row with:

"MS-DRG V38 (FY 2021)"
"MS-DRG V39 (FY 2022)"
and so on...

Being new to SQL I hoped that a formula like the one below would work:

```
WHERE   ID_TYPE_NAME LIKE 'MS-DRG%'
    and ID_TYPE_NAME LIKE YEAR(CURDATE())
```

but I get a message that

> CURDATE is not a recognized built-in function name

Can I use like or do I need to go a different route? If I must go a different route, what method do I use to accomplish this?

Comment: What's your SQL dialect? `CURDATE()` is not a standard function.

Comment: to be honest, i dont know. i just started learning on TOAD for SQL server. should i use getdate?

Comment: TOAD is just the program you use to interact with the database engine. You are using Microsoft SQL Server, so that's the documentation you need to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `CONCAT` to build the string which should be found, something like this:

```
SELECT ID_TYPE_NAME
FROM yourtable
WHERE ID_TYPE_NAME 
LIKE CONCAT('MS-DRG%',YEAR(GETDATE()),')');
```

`YEAR` takes just the year from the whole current date.

So the `LIKE` condition will be created as: `MS-DRG%2022)`

Or we can be even more specific and do this:

```
SELECT ID_TYPE_NAME
FROM yourtable
WHERE ID_TYPE_NAME 
LIKE CONCAT('MS-DRG%FY ',YEAR(GETDATE()),')');
```

The `LIKE` condition of this query will be created as: `MS-DRG%FY 2022)`

Both queries will return only this result from your sample data: `MS-DRG V39 (FY 2022)`

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WA3q8cA4)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing magical about `LIKE` arguments, it's just a regular string where certain characters (namely `%` and `_`) are handled as wildcard characters. Your error about `CURDATE` not being recognized as built-in function is because you're calling a function that doesn't exist, just like if you run `select pink_elephants()`.

To compose a string with a pattern that suits your needs you can use these tools:

- `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to get current date and time (this is a feature from standard SQL that's available in many dialects)
- `YEAR()` to extract year portion
- `CAST()` to convert year (an integer) to text
- `+` to concatenate substrings

All together:

```
where id_type_name like 'MS-DRG% (FY ' + cast(year(current_timestamp) as varchar(4)) + ')'
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9Pkgbro5)

Comment: Is `CONCAT()` not more standard than `+ to concatenate substrings` ?

Comment: @Luuk Yes, it is. The `+` operator is exclusive to SQL Server.